# Daisy chain variadic templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a class  template Pipeline:

```
template <typename A, typename B> class Pipeline;
```

I'd like to create a variadic function template accepting an arbitrary number of arbitrary `Pipeline`s, and I'd like to constrain those in a tricky way. Non variadic code would look like:

```
Pipeline<A, C> compose(Pipeline<A, B> p1, Pipeline<B, C> p2);
Pipeline<A, D> compose(Pipeline<A, B> p1, Pipeline<B, C> p2, Pipeline<C, D> p3);
// ...and so on
```

Now is it possible at all to constrain them end-to-end in a variadic way?

```
// I would like to write something like:
Pipeline<Args[0], Args[len(Args)-1]> compose(Pipeline<Args[i], Args[i+1]> ps...);
```

Comment: can you show as the definition of Pipeline?

Comment: It can certainly be done. It might be a bit verbose.

Comment: `template<typename A, typename B> struct Pipeline { B run(A); }` should do the trick. It's basically a verbosified function 'A -> B', and I want to write function composition.

Comment: Start with a metafunction that gets a pair out of a list: `Pair<2, T1, T2, T3, T4> == T2, T3`, etc. Ultimately you want something like `f(Pair<Idx, Args>...)`

Comment: Is `Pipeline` itself a variadic template, or just two types? It's unclear from the wording of your question.

Comment: @Barry: just two types -- `Pipeline<Args...>` was wrong, I edited my question. You got it right in your answer at "pick out the first and last types".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that your `Pipeline` looks something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Pipeline {
    using first = A;
    using second = B;
};
```

First, let's make a type trait for what's a valid chain link:

```
template <typename P1, typename P2>
struct is_valid_link : std::false_type { };

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct is_valid_link<Pipeline<A,B>, Pipeline<B,C>> : std::true_type { };
```

Next, let's borrow @Columbo's `bool_pack` trick to verify that bunch of `bool`s are all `true`:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;

template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;
```

And of course we need the index sequence trick:

```
template <typename... Pipelines,
          typename R = decltype(detail::daisy_chain(
                                    std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Pipelines)-1>(),
                                    std::declval<Pipelines>()...))
         >
R compose(Pipelines... pipelines)
{
    return {};
}
```

Where the bulk of the work is doing the checking here:

```
namespace detail {
    template <size_t... Is,
              typename... Pipelines,
              typename T = std::tuple<Pipelines...>,
              typename R = std::enable_if_t<
                          // ensure that all our pairwise pipelines are valid links
                                all_true<
                                    is_valid_link<std::tuple_element_t<Is,T>,
                                                  std::tuple_element_t<Is+1,T>>::value...
                                    >::value,
                           // pick out the first and last types
                                Pipeline<typename std::tuple_element_t<0, T>::first,
                                         typename std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Pipelines)-1, T>::second>
                            >>
    R daisy_chain(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Pipelines... pipelines);
}
```

That lets us do:

```
int main() {
    Pipeline<int, double> p = compose(Pipeline<int, char>{}, Pipeline<char, double>{});
}
```

The advantage of writing it this way is that you still have SFINAE - if that's something you want. Such that:

```
auto invalid = compose(Pipeline<int, char>{}, Pipeline<float, double>{});
```

will trigger an overload resolution failure:

```
main.cpp:46:31: error: no matching function for call to 'compose'
    Pipeline<int, double> p = compose(Pipeline<int, char>{}, Pipeline<float, double>{});
                              ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:40:3: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Pipelines = <Pipeline<int, char>, Pipeline<float, double>>]: no matching function for call to 'daisy_chain'
R compose(Pipelines... pipelines)
  ^
1 error generated.
```